# what happened when I call setTimeout in for loop?

Tags: javascript

Please run the code snippet, as you see, the console output as follow:

```
1
...
5
6 (5 times)
```

So far as I know, `setTimeout` create a new function stack, but `i<=5` should be stop when `i == 5`, So I can't understand why `6`.

[This is MDN about explain `setTimeout`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

from 1 to 5 I is very simple to understand, but what happened when call `setTimeout`, and how to explain `6` exist in console?

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i)
    }, 0)
}
```

Comment: The loop is executed first, then the delayed functions. At that time the value of `i` is 6. Also, `timer` and `clearInterval` are meaningless to the `setTimeout` in the code.

Comment: @Teemu I remove some meaningless code which my another demo left.

Answer (score 0):

The first `console.log` call gets run five times in a row before the ones in setTimeout ever start. Then, `i` is 6, and `console.log(i)` gets called those five times that are all queued up.

When you run setTimeout, it returns a handle to the timer. You're not actually doing anything with the return value, but it's still on the queue.

Also, a timeout value of 0 doesn't technically mean "run right now", it just means "add to the top of the queue".

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i)
    }, 0)
}
```

var creates a variable which isn't scoped to the for loop's block (it's not block scoped), whereas let does this. Therefore the functions created with the setTimeout invocations will all look at the same var and hence print 6 (which its value by the time they'll have a chance to run, while with let, they have a closure over this block scoped variable, hence all correctly print their intended values, 1..5.